# How do I count the frequency of an item in a new column, without changing the structure of the table? SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am having the following problem. **I have to count the number of items for a table as a new column. Without changing the out put apart from the extra column.**

As it is quite complicated i will try to provide a good example  to explain what I mean:

The input table:

```
BS         item_id     price
-------------------------------
BS1          3        10
BS1          5        12 
BS3          6        15 
BS3          7        18 
BS4          8         5
BS1          9        10
```

The count should add the column Amount. **The amount is based on BS.**

```
BS         item_id     price      Amount
    -------------------------------
    BS1          3        10        3
    BS1          5        12        3
    BS3          6        15        2
    BS3          7        18        2
    BS4          5        12        1
    BS1          8        10        3
```

I would like to know if it is possible to use count with a subquery in order to get the amount like i showed above.

When I use count like below in the code, i get for every BS item the value 1

```
SELECT COUNT(bsc_bsc_id)AS Amount,
                  katg_katg_id,
                  ex_wert 
from (
        SELECT bs_bs_id,
               katg_katg_id,
               jahr,
               TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (a.jahr || a.monat, 'YYYYMM'), 'YYYYMM') AS monat_key,
               bsc_bsc_id,
               buchg_date,
               ex_wert,
               vp_wert
 FROM  fis_buchg_schl a
```

The code above is more or less pseudo code since i took big parts away because it was too long. A hint in the right direction to solve my problem would be great.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using - SQLServer, Oracle, ...?

Comment: you will have to do nested queries\

Comment: sorry for not writing it. I am using oracle ; )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQLServer 2005 or later, try:

```
Select BS, item_id, price, 
       count(*) over (partition by BS) Amount
from yourTable
```

EDIT: Should work for Oracle, too.

Comment: thank you. Apparently oracle also user the tag over: count() OVER ( [ query_partition_clause] ORDER BY clause ). I didn't know about that tag. ; )

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT A.BS,A.ITEM_ID,A.PRICE,B.COUNT_BS
FROM
(SELECT BS,ITEM_ID,PRICE
 FROM YOURINPUTTABLE) A, 
(SELECT BS,COUNT(BS) AS COUNT_BS
 FROM YOURINPUTTABLE
 GROUP BY BS) B
WHERE A.BS = B.BS;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I chose Mark Bannisters answer since his was shorter and the performance was better.